# Keydown won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

I have been reading many post here but I just don't get why my code doesn't work. I have another page with lightbox image slider. It has keystroke for keycode 39 and 37. Would that override my code and make it not working? I am a beginner of Jquery user, please explain it in detail.

```
   <span class="pageLinks">
      <asp:HyperLink ID="cmdPrev_Top" CssClass="pgprev" Text="" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="cmdNext_Top" CssClass="pgnext" Text="" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
   </span>


   $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).bind('keydown', function (event) {
        var keycode = event.keyCode;
        if (key == 37) {
            left(function () {
                $('.pgprev').click();
                alert(prev);
            });
        } else if (key == 39) {
            right(function () {
                $('pgnext').click();
                alert(next);
            });
        }
    }); // keydown handler ends here
});
```

Comment: Use `which` property instead of `keyCode`.

Comment: replacing the var line to "var key = e.which || e.keyCode;"?

Comment: jQuery normalizes the Event object, the `which` property works in all browsers that jQuery supports, there is no need to check other browser-specific properties.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your variable names seem to be different.
You have:

```
var keycode = event.keyCode;
```

Then

```
if (key == 37) {
```

And

```
} else if (key == 39){
```

Where does `key` come from?

Comment: thanks, I post the code in rush. I should have had check my code carefully before posting it. pgnext class should be .pgnext too. I have correct all of them, but it still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

The variable name is keyCode not key! This code should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(document).bind('keydown', function (event) {
    var keycode = event.keyCode;
    if (keycode  == 37) {
        left(function () {
            $('.pgprev').click();
            alert("prev");
        });
    } else if (keycode  == 39) {
        right(function () {
            $('pgnext').click();
            alert("next");
        });
    }
}); // keydown handler ends here
});
```

Comment: i corrected the minor mistake .pgnext class and alert text with "". and use the keycode instead key. it still doesn't work. I wonder if my homepage's lightbox keystroke would override this one?

Comment: $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       alert( "left pressed" );
       return false;
    }
});  the alert popup when i press left arrow key. I just don't understand why original code don't work.

Comment: @user2734550 or you should change you variables' names within the keydown function...